# Delete from two table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to delete data from two tables at a time.

**Example**:

Table 1:

```
create table del1
(
cola varchar(10) primary key,
colb varchar(10)
);
```

Table 2:

```
create table del2
(
cola varchar(10) foreign key references del1(cola) on delete cascade,
colb varchar(10)
)
```

Inserting some data:

```
insert into del1 values('a','b');
insert into del2 values('a','d');
```

Query to delete the records:

```
delete from del1 as d1
inner join del2 as d2
on d1.cola= d2.cola 
where d1.cola= 'a'
```

**Error**:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `on` condition was meant to reference `d2` there. Is the actual delete condition in the `where` clause actually based on `cola` (`colb` is irrelevant, and so it could also, as easily, reference `d2` instead of `d1`)?

Comment: [Why can't I use an alias in a DELETE statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005209/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-in-a-delete-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually u dont need to join the two table's. `delete` on **del1 table** it will automatically delete the **del2 table** since u have `on delete cascade`

This is what you need.

```
delete from del1 where cola='a'
```

This statement will delete from del1 where cola='a' and also the del2 table where cola='a'

Answer (score 2):

Join is Not needed. Due to `On Cascade delete` it will delete both records

```
delete from del1 where  cola= 'a'
```