# MYSQL query gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running this query on phpmyadmin and it gives a syntax error,

```
Delete from users_roles as ur where ur.uid NOT IN (select u.uid from users as u)

ERROR: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as ur where ur.uid NOT IN (select u.uid from users as u)' at line 1
```

and when I am running this query

```
select ur.uid from users_roles as ur where ur.uid NOT IN (select u.uid from users as u)
```

it gives me the result.

Comment: Add the error message please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing alias:

```
Delete from users_roles where uid NOT IN (select uid from users)
```

See the demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ba733).

**EDIT:**

When you are in need to use alias for delete query (when you use joined query), you can do :

```
Delete ur from users_roles as ur where ur.uid NOT IN (select u.uid from users as u)
```

Comment: Thanks, Raging Bull, It works for me, can u please explain what was the problem with the alias.

Comment: @AkashJain: See the edit in my answer. Also see [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005209/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-in-a-delete-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias in that form of the `DELETE` statement. It should be:

```
DELETE FROM users_roles 
WHERE uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM users)
```

To use an alias, you have to use a different syntax:

```
DELETE ur FROM users_roles AS ur
WHERE ur.uid NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM users)
```

This syntax is usually only used when you're performing a `JOIN` in the `DELETE` statement, so that you need to refer to specific tables and columns in the `JOIN`. It's not needed when you're just referring to one table. For instance, you could rewrite the query as:

```
DELETE ur
FROM users_roles AS ur
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON ur.uid = u.uid
WHERE u.uid IS NULL
```

See the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html). The first form of `DELETE` only allows ***tbl_name***, the second form allows ***table_references***, and the latter is where aliases can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

don t use alias for delete try this 
Delete from users_roles as where users_roles.uid NOT IN (select u.uid from users as u)