# Incorrect syntax near 'C'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the section of code that is getting an error. I am not sure why I am getting an error.

```
Delete from TblProcessCurrency C
where Not Exists (
    Select PRCSchedule
    from tblProcess P 
    where P.PrcSchedule = C.PCXSchedule and P.PRCOlsn = C.PCXOlsn and P.PRCRelease = C.PCXRelease
);
```

and here is the error I am getting

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
>   Incorrect syntax near 'C'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use an alias in a DELETE statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005209/why-cant-i-use-an-alias-in-a-delete-statement)

Comment: If you want to a more intuitive `delete` statement, you may rewrite this using a `join`. Resource on that https://sqlstudies.com/2013/09/24/dba-myths-you-cant-use-an-alias-in-a-delete-statement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
DELETE C
FROM TblProcessCurrency C 
WHERE Not Exists...
```

You can't alias the table that is the target for the `DELETE`, unless you state you want to `DELETE` from said alias.